# Error formating Date on JSP

Tags: java, jsp

I am trying to format a date field to yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss instead of yyyy-MM-dd.

On my JSP I got:

```
layout:collectionItem title="reclam.alter.dataInicio" type="date" property="dataInicio" styleClass="layout_center"/>
<fmt:formatDate pattern="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" value="${idAlterLote.dataInicio}" /> &nbsp;
```

But I am getting the error:

```
`avax.servlet.ServletException: format date failed (Invocation target exception: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String incompatible with java.util.Date)`
```

On my Bean, my variable is using java.util.Date.

Like this:

```
public Date getDataFim() {
    return dataFim;
}
public void setDataFim(Date dataFim) {
    this.dataFim = dataFim;
}
public Date getDataInicio() {
    return dataInicio;
}
public void setDataInicio(Date dataInicio) {
    this.dataInicio = dataInicio;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like `idAlterLote.dataInicio` is actually a string and not a date.

Comment: @MickMnemonic question edited.

Comment: Please share a minimal but _complete_ example of the problem. We don't know what e.g. `idAlterLote` is.